# Basic Scala Errors That Make No Sense

Tags: java, scala, types

I'm trying to get a function to compile/work in scala, and getting several absolutely inane error messages that I just can't make sense of. If I write my code like this:

```
def checkUniqueReviewNumber(number: String): Boolean = {
    val qc = new QualityClient
    if(review.isEmpty)
      false
    else {
      val qrList = qc.listInPL(Vars.currentPLId.get.get,null,null,null,null,null,null,false,false,CurrentUser.getUser.key).qualityReviews
      !qrList.exists(qr:QualityReview => qr.reviewNumber == number)
    }
  }
```

I get the error:

```
.../QualityReviewCreate.scala:189: error: not found: type ==
   [scalac]       !qrList.exists(qr:QualityReview => qr.reviewNumber == number)
```

And if I write the code more like this:

```
def checkUniqueReviewNumber(number: String): Boolean = {
    val qc = new QualityClient
    if(review.isEmpty)
      false
    else {
      val qrList = qc.listInPL(Vars.currentPLId.get.get,null,null,null,null,null,null,false,false,CurrentUser.getUser.key).qualityReviews
      !qrList.exists(qr:QualityReview => qr.reviewNumber.equals(number))
    }
  }
```

I get the errors:

```
... /QualityReviewCreate.scala:189: error: ')' expected but '(' found.
   [scalac]       !qrList.exists(qr:QualityReview => qr.reviewNumber.equals(number))
   [scalac]                                                                ^
    ... /QualityReviewCreate.scala:189: error: ';' expected but ')' found.
   [scalac]       !qrList.exists(qr:QualityReview => qr.reviewNumber.equals(number))
   [scalac]                                                                        ^
   [scalac] two errors found
```

The types involved may be contributing here, but if so I'm absolutely confused as to why. qrList should be a java ArrayList of QualityReview, which is a java object with a java String field called reviewNumber.

Does anyone understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 22):

The problem is that Scala's parsing for anonymous functions with explicit argument types is ambiguous, and sometimes that leads to some very strange quirks.  This is one of them.  Take the following expression:

```
(qr:QualityReview => qr.reviewNumber == number)
```

Scala is (apparently) parsing this as follows:

```
(qr:(QualityReview => qr.reviewNumber == number))
```

This isn't what you wanted.  In fact, it's not even an anonymous function.  Desugaring the expression yields the following:

```
(qr: Function1[QualityReview, ==[qr.reviewNumber, number]])
```

So in other words, we are ascribing a type to `qr`, where that type is given by `Function1` parameterized with `QualityReview` and the type given by `==` parameterized by the types `qr.reviewNumber` and `number`.  All of this is valid Scala, and I suspect none of it is what you intended.

The error comes about when Scala goes looking for a type with name `==`, which of course it doesn't find (it *could* exist, but it doesn't).  If it had gotten past that error, it would have quickly run into issues finding types `qr.reviewNumber` and `number`.

There are a couple ways to avoid this issue.  In general, I would just recommend using a slightly different style when declaring your functions.  The [Scala Style Guide](http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/) is a good place to start.  In the case of this function, the easiest way to fix the problem is to drop the type annotation (`QualityReview`).  You could also solve the problem by putting parentheses around `qr:QualityReview`.  Also, I think a space after the colon might fix the issue, though I can't be sure.  Finally, using curly braces rather than parentheses usually makes the compiler prefer interpreting `=>` as a lambda delimiter rather than a type.  I would have written your `exists` expression in the following way:

```
!(qrList exists { qr => qr.reviewNumber == number })
```

Actually, I probably would have used the underscore syntax, but that's an entirely different question.  :-)

```
!(qrList exists { _.reviewNumber == number })
```

Answer (score 8):

in short, you just have to add parentheses around your parameter list; i.e.,

```
!qrList.exists((qr:QualityReview) => qr.reviewNumber == number)
```

same applies to the second attempt with .equals

here is a good rundown of the function sugar
http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/09/scala-syntax-primer.html#funcdef